# How to find remainder when determinant is divided by 5

Tags: algebra-precalculus, number-theory, determinant

$$A= \begin{vmatrix}
2014^{2014} &  2015^{2015} & 2016^{2016}\\ 
         2017^{2017} &  2018^{2018} & 2019^{2019} \\
         2020^{2020} &  2021^{2021} & 2022^{2022}
\end{vmatrix}$$

I thought I would have to find the value if the determinant, but it is obviously too large to be found. Is there a shortcut to solving this?

Comment: Why would anybody want to do that, with or without shortcut?

Comment: The result is a 20,000 digit number: should this be evaluated modulo something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Hint:* The determinant is a polynomial expression in the entries and so you can reduce the entries mod $5$ before expanding. Also, use Fermat's little theorem.

Solution:

The argument is based on repeated application of this general fact about congruences:

> If $a \equiv a' \bmod m$ and $b \equiv b' \bmod m$, then $a \pm b \equiv a' \pm b' \bmod m$ and $ab \equiv a'b' \bmod m$.

Thus, $2014^{2014} \equiv 4^{2014} \bmod 5$ because $2014 \equiv 4 \bmod 5$. Fermat's little theorem gives $4^4 \equiv 1 \bmod 5$. Therefore, $2014^{2014} \equiv 4^{2} \equiv 1\bmod 5$ because $2014 \equiv 2 \bmod 4$.

Repeat this computation for all entries of the determinant to reduce it to a determinant involving only $0,1,2,3,4$, which should be easy to compute.

Comment: @thomas, $p(a_1,\dots,a_n) \equiv p(a_1 \bmod m,\dots,a_n  \bmod m)  \bmod m$

Comment: Following that, is 2015^{2015} = 5^5 and 2016^(2016)=1 and 2017^(2017)=2 ? (I have a feeling I still haven't got it)

Comment: @thomas, $2015 \equiv 0 \bmod 5$. The others are correct. The point is to reduce the basis mod $5$ and the exponent mod $4$ when the basis is not reduced to $0$.

Comment: Using that... I get 2015^2015=0... 2018^2018=3²; 2019^2019=4^3; 2020^2020=0; 2021^2021=1; and 2022^2022=2²... And on solving the determinant, I get the remainder as one. (Thanks)